# Telnet login as linux user with a prompt

Tags: telnet

I'm trying to figure out the setup of port 23 on an Ubuntu server. It was setup by my predecessor in quite a tricky way and now I need to migrate the functionality to a new machine. I know roughly how it functions, but I don't know the details, which is what I need to know now. The rough functionality is this:

- Users log in to the server as a regular linux user via port 23 (always with the same user). More detail on this below...
- Once logged in, they are presented with a prompt for some information
- They enter information at the prompt and then it logs them out

I can see that the default shell is bash (username and number modified for privacy):

```
# grep theuser /etc/passwd
theuser:x:1111:1111::/home/theuser:/bin/bash
```

And I can see that the `.bash_profile` script redirects the user to the prompts upon login:

```
$ cat /home/theuser/.bash_profile 
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts

export PATH
unset USERNAME

/home/theuser/scripts/prompts
exit
```

So there is no mystery there. However the question I have is how on earth can port 23 be linked to the login prompt of a regular linux user? I know for sure that this is the case because I can login as follows:

```
$ telnet localhost 23
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
machinename login: theuser
Password:
Last login: Fri Mar 24 14:25:48 CST 2017 from localhost on pts/5
prompt 1:
```

If I check for processes running on port 23 then I get:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 23
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2222/inetd
```

So the connection is handled by `inetd`. But that doesn't help me out because I don't know what `inetd` is doing. If I look in `/etc/inetd.conf` then I see the following line:

```
telnet      stream  tcp nowait  root    /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

But that's not much help. I already knew `telnet` was running on this machine. I need to know how `telnet` is configured to redirect the user to a login prompt.

Comment: `inetd` listens to TCP (or UDP) ports, and hands down connections to other special crafted programs (typically named `in.<mumble>`), which in turn simply use `stdin` / `stdout` instead of dealing with network communications themselves.  One such special crafted program is `in.telnetd`, which is the `telnet` server. See `man inetd` and `man in.telnetd` for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a TELNET server listening on TCP port 23 is not "tricky".  It is *normal* (as long as one discounts the abnormality of using TELNET at all in this century).  That is the *well known port number* for TELNET service.

And `in.telnetd` is not "configured" to "redirect" the user to a login prompt.  Presenting a login interface to connected clients is *what it does*.  Its manual page (q.v.) is quite explicit:

> Telnetd operates by allocating a pseudo-terminal device […] for a client, then creating a login process which has the slave side of the pseudo-terminal as stdin, stdout and stderr. Telnetd manipulates the master side of the pseudo-terminal, implementing the telnet protocol and passing characters between the remote client and the login process.

The *login process* is running the `login` program, presenting that login prompt.

Comment: its tricky because this is the first i (and i suspect many others of my age) have ever heard of being able to log in to linux using telnet. though now i have done some reading on it, i'm getting a better picture of how this all works.

Comment: @mulllhausen You never heard of this configuration because everybody has been discouraging its use for the past ~25 years.  In the vast majority of cases it's more appropriate to use `ssh` instead.